# How to scroll by pixels in karate framework

Tags: user-interface, scroll, automated-tests, karate, gui-testing

I want to scroll by pixels in karate framework.

I have tried this:

```
* def scrollDown =
"""
function () {
var results = window.scrollTo(0,500);
return results;
}
"""
* call scrollDown
```

And I got this error:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PloyglotException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script function to execute any JavaScript snippet.

```
function () {
   var results = script('window.scrollTo(0,500)');
   return results;
}
```

More information can be found at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#script

Comment: I think this is correct. OP should also read: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser